# Is "fallace" a word representative of "fallacy," or some variant spelling?

Tags: roots

Is there a form of the word *fallacy* as such: something along the lines of erroneous, or at fault, some version of the word *fallacy* without the 'y'. Otherwise what are some good suggestions that ring true to the word *fallacy*, as I feel *erroneous* is not quite the right word to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fallacious" is I think the word wanted

- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fallacious) gives the senses:

> - 1 embodying a fallacy : *a fallacious conclusion; a fallacious argument*
> - 2 tending to deceive or mislead : *delusive false and fallacious hopes*

- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fallacious) gives:

> not correct: *His argument is based on fallacious reasoning.*

It lists as synonyms:

- erroneous formal
- false (NOT CORRECT)
- incorrect
- untrue
- wrong (NOT CORRECT)
- [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/fallacious) states:

> If an idea, argument, or reason is fallacious, it is wrong because it is based on a fallacy.